# Developing apps for Near Field Communication (NFC)

Tags: mobile, nfc

Please point me to a toolkit i can use to build Near Field Communication apps.

thanks

Comment: What's your hardware platform and programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to experience NFC with Android - get the SDK here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Right now NFC is a feature which cannot be emulated using the emulator. so you will need to buy an actual device. The SDK demo also has a FakeTagsActivity but I'd not recommend it as you might introduce bugs and verify only that your code works based on your own assumptions about NFC.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Contactless Communication API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/nfc/#3) for Java.

Comment: I am using open nfc API by INSIDE Contactless..but i am unable to configure the connection center for the NFC .any idea as on from where i can access the connection manager which they have mentioned in the PDF which come with the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get started you most often need to get the hardware. Such as NXP, ACS, Omnikey etc. Then you can purchase an SDK with the product (omnikey has it included), they usually contain SDK's for JAVA, C and/or C#.

Answer (score 0):

Android supports NFC as of Android 2.3

There is a demo project in the SDK

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [NDEF eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) which lets you compose NDEF messages, and write to tags using a corresponding (free) Android (4.0) app.

It is based on the [nfctools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) toolkit, and targeted at entry level developers.

Also I have added the [NDEF Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) for which you might be interested - helps handling NDEF messages at runtime.